# Ormlite throwing SQLException on create(). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, sqlite, ormlite

I'm trying to replace existing database code with Ormlite in a Java project I'm working on.

However, when I call create() to insert an object into the SQLite database, it throws a SQLException. I figure I'm probably making an obvious mistake, but I can't figure out what it is. Here is the code:

```
public class OrmliteTest {
    private final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:test.sqlite";
    private JdbcConnectionSource connectionSource = null;
    private Dao<Article, Integer> articleDao;

    public OrmliteTest() throws SQLException{
        connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(DATABASE_URL);

        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, Article.class);

        articleDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Article.class);

        Article article1 = new Article("articles", "idnumber", "blah blah blah", (int)(new Date().getTime()/1000));

        articleDao.createOrUpdate(article1); // throws SQLException - why?
    }
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "articles")
class Article {
    public static final String CATEGORY_FIELD_NAME = "category";
    public static final String ARTICLEID_FIELD_NAME = "articleid";
    public static final String BODY_FIELD_NAME = "body";
    public static final String ADDED_FIELD_NAME = "added";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = CATEGORY_FIELD_NAME)
    public String category;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = ARTICLEID_FIELD_NAME)
    public String articleId;

@DatabaseField(columnName = BODY_FIELD_NAME)
    public String body;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = ADDED_FIELD_NAME)
    public int added;

    public Article() {}

    public Article(String category, String articleId, String body, int added) {
        setCategory(category);
        setArticleId(articleId);
        setBody(body);
        setAdded(added);
    }

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

The exception is thrown on the call to `articleDao.createOrUpdate(article1)`. Here is the traceback:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object com.myapp.tester.Article@7a36824: INSERT INTO `articles` (`category` ,`storyid` ,`body` ,`added` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:90)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.create(StatementExecutor.java:325)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:287)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:312)
    at com.myapp.tester.OrmliteBugTester.<init>(OrmliteBugTester.java:128)
    at com.myapp.tester.Tester.main(Tester.java:24)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: NYI
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:217)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.insert(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:105)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedCreate.insert(MappedCreate.java:63)
    ... 5 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you are using the right SQLite driver with [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  I know the Zentus driver throws NYI exceptions a lot.  Here's the manual:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/sqlite

To quote:

> There are multiple SQLite drivers out there. Make sure you use the [Xerial](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) driver and not the [Zentus](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) driver which does not support generated ids.

Comment: Hi! But how can I specify Xerial driver for using with my DB properly?

Comment: @Yarovoy This is for JDBC connections -- not Android.  You just need to include the Xerial jar with your project.

Comment: Hi I'm getting the "java.sql.SQLException: NYI" i'm using maven to mange my dependency, following is the  snap of my pom.xml, please let me know how can i correct this exception. <dependency><groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId><artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId><version>4.41</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId><artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId><version>4.41</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>org.xerial</groupId><artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId><version>3.6.16</version></dependency></dependencies>

Comment: Please use the ORMLite mailing list for this @Sam.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ormlite-user

Answer (score 0):

Well afaik NYI means Not Yet Implemented. I think this thing doesn't support parametrised SQL. Try hardcoding the values you wanna insert directly in your update query String and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of SQLite it looks like `NYI` stands for *not yet implemented*.

Your version simply isn't completely implemented/done. Upgrade to 3.6.20 which doesn't seem to have these exceptions anymore.